# Java JAR can't find file

Tags: file, jar, reference, path, load

I am running a program in eclipse that references a file in the program's source folder. However, when I export the program into a runnable JAR, the program cannot seem to find the file. Essentially, the program works perfect in eclipse but doesn't do so when it's a standalone program.

I've attached a photo of how I reference the file in the program.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Once it's in the jar, you can't find it using `new File()` -- it's now a class path resource.  You need to use `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/TestFileFolder/TRANSFER.xls");` (or, if your method is static, you need to use the `className.class` in place of `getClass()`).

this is actually a feature -- if for any reason you need to change the `TRANSFER.xls` resource, you can do so by shadowing it in the classpath without repacking the jar.

Comment: So what will be returned from 'this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/TestFileFolder/TRANSFER.xls");'? I'm confused as to what this will give me and where I will put that.

Comment: Never mind. I realized what you showed would replace the file input stream. This seemed to solve my problem.

Comment: Then why don't you accept the answer by clicking on the checkbox?