# java.io.IOException: Stream closed, when trying to access an XML file from JAR

Tags: java, file, jar, path, reference

I'm trying to refer to a XML file into my project so i can parse the data from it.

It is being exported as a `.jar` file which means **i can't** refer to it using

```java
 BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("PhillPlugin.xml"));
```

which **works perfectly** when i run it from the **JDeveloper IDE**

So i replace the line above with the following line:

```java
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(Class1.class.getResourceAsStream("Resources/PhillPlugin.xml"));
```

But when i'm executing the `.jar` file

`java -jar test.jar` in terminal

the `java.io.IOException: Stream closed` is being triggered.

> **It's mandatory to do it using Streams and not with any Parsing XML libraries**

This is where my files are located:

[image]

This is how i'm trying to read it:

[image]

Based on this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20451386/java-jar-cant-find-file)

Here is the code if you want to try it:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) throws  Exception {

     /*This is line 21*/   BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(Class1.class.getResourceAsStream("Resources/PhillPlugin.xml"));


        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String genurl=null;
        int cp;
        while ((cp = in.read()) != -1) {
            sb.append((char) cp);
            String t = sb.toString();
            if(t.contains("</AttributeValuePair>"))
            {
                String test = sb.toString();
                String test1p[]=test.split("<value>|</value>");
                genurl=test1p[1];
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(genurl);
        sb=new StringBuilder();
        while ((cp = in.read()) != -1) {

            sb.append((char) cp);
            String t = sb.toString();
            if(t.contains("</AttributeValuePair>"))
            {
                String test = sb.toString();
                String test1p[]=test.split("<value>|</value>");
                genurl=test1p[1];
                System.out.println(genurl);
                break;
            }

        }
        in.close();
    }
```

---

This is the stacktrace i'm getting from the `terminal` **after the correct reference to the path**

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: PhillPlugin.xml (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at client.Class1.main(Class1.java:21)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you manage to read some bytes at all ? Also at which line does the error occur ?

Comment: no haven't tried reading bytes, it occures on the BufferedInputStream

Comment: Just noticed that the  "Resource"  part of the path doesn't match the name of the actual directory, which is  "Resources"  .

Comment: Whops, thank you i'm going to fix it, but no, it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the JAR file is created from the project in the normal way, the correct resource path for that XML file will be `"/PhillPlugin.xml"` not `"Resource/PhillPlugin.xml"`.

Assuming that `Class1.class` is in the default package, and you use `Class::getResourceAsStream`, the relative path `"PhillPlugin.xml"` should work as well.

Use `jar tvf your.jar` to check that the XML file is in the JAR, and what the resource path for the XML file actually is.

Comment: Right, the `/PhillPlugin.xml` worked, but when i'm running the `.jar` i'm getting the `FileNotFoundException`

Comment: Nothing in the code you have shown us can throw `FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: Also my two loops work, i'm getting the expected result, there is a `break` in the first loop

Comment: Ah ... I missed that.

Comment: correct, but when i execute the `.jar` it's being triggered

Comment: Maybe you have the path for the JAR file wrong.

Comment: I'm running `ls` and i can see the `test.jar` file, so i suppose i'm in the right path to run `java -jar test.jar`

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace to the question.

Comment: i did , line 21 is this one `BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(Class1.class.getResourceAsStream("/PhillPlugin.xml"));`

Comment: That stacktrace clearly shows that main is `new`-ing a `FileInputStream`.  The code you showed us doesn't do that.  Like I said in my earlier comment .  Have you forgotten to recompile?

Comment: Yes, that's odd, remember that `Class1.class.getResourceAsStream()` returns an `InputStream` , is it being converted to `FileInputStream` from the `BufferedInputStream`'s Constructor?

Comment: Nope.  The stacktrace shows that main line 21 has an explicit `new FileInputStream(...)` expression.  Trust me.  I fave been programming in Java for > 20 years.

Comment: OH MY i forgot to re - `Deploy` the `.JAR` file. Works perfectly thank you.I'm sorry i missed that

Answer (score 1):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author; copied from the solution they placed in the question)*.

I forgot to re-deploy he .JAR file after the change. It works perfectly now