# Tomcat 9 specify config folder path

Tags: java, tomcat

I am running in Tomcat 9 an app that needs to read several .config files but I get an `java.io.IOException`.

These .config files are located in `WebContent` folder.

How can I tell Tomcat to read this path?
Can be related to IntelliJ settings for the project?

This is how is loaded the config file:

```
 ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();

InputStream is = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(this.configFile);
```

Value of this.configFile is: cnp-filter.config

Comment: You need to get them from CLASSPATH and not from filesystem. Look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20451386/java-jar-cant-find-file

Comment: Yes it gets it from classpath actually @Michal

Comment: could you please show us the code used to read those resources?  Further, could you also show the exact stacktrace produced by the error? ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream() does not actually throw IOException as of JDK 9 JavaDoc.

Comment: Sure I am adding it. The strange thing is that the code was working before on a WebSphere server.

Comment: @Michal I have added it in the post.

Comment: Could you please add the StackTrace of the error? Further the value of `this.configFile` would be of interest.

Comment: Added stacktrace and value of configFile @Michal

Comment: If the value is preceded by `/`, i.e. `/cnp-filter.config` does  it still  not work?

Comment: I have it - they must be in WEB-INF/clases not WEB-INF.

Comment: src/main/resources or use ServletContext to read them - see my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221813/discussion-between-michal-and-stefano-maglione).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CLASSPATH resources need to be under `WEB-INF/classes`. Please put the config files under `src/main/resources` for a maven project.

Alternatively, resources directly under `WEB-INF` are accessible via `ServletContext#getResourceAsStream(String path)`.

Comment: At the moment .config files are in Webcontent folder, where I should put them?

Comment: `src/main/resources` provided it is a maven project? the default package of Java classes if it is not a maven project.

Comment: I do not have src/main/resources but I have projectName/resources/, what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
InputStream input = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("your absolute path ");
```

this might helpful.

Comment: Yes I am using the same, but still issues.

Comment: try to give full path